# Negative form of isinstance() in Python

Tags: python, negate, negation, isinstance

How would I use a negative form of Python's isinstance()?

Normally negation would work something like

```
x != 1

if x not in y

if not a
```

I just haven't seen an example with isinstance(), so I'd like to know if there's a correct way to used negation with isinstance().

Comment: So you don't mean `not isinstance(...)`?

Comment: so you need to learn how to use `not` for every python construction?

Comment: This is still the Summer of Love, everyone.  To be fair, that `not in` works shows that you don't need to have the `not` before the expression but sometimes it can float around a bit, and it's possible that there could have been a preferred Pythonic way other than `not isinstance()`.  For example, there could have been some subtle corner case which meant you should use a different form (rather like `type(obj) is list` works sometimes but is suboptimal.)

Comment: There are two special forms: `x is not y` means the same as `not(x is y)`, and `x not in y` means the same as `not(x in y)`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just use `not`.  `isinstance` just returns a `bool`, which you can `not` like any other.

Answer (score 33):

That would seem strange, but:

```
if not isinstance(...):
   ...
```

The `isinstance` function returns a boolean value. That means that you can negate it (or make any other logical operations like `or` or `and`).

Example:

```
>>> a="str"
>>> isinstance(a, str)
True
>>> not isinstance(a, str)
False
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use `not`, e.g.,

```
if not isinstance(someVariable, str):
     ....
```

You are simply negating the "truth value" (ie Boolean) that [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) is returning.